# How to debug events not firing after clicking continue button?

Tags: protractor, debugging

I have an automated script that fills out guest information and clicks a 'Save and Continue' button to proceed to the next page. The button is being clicked correctly because it becomes disabled but the next page never loads. The rest of the tests then fail because the new page is not loading. This works fine when using the same steps and information manually. I've added sleeps but it looks like after clicking continue, the request isn't being sent.

How can I determine what event isn't firing correctly? From what I have seen, dev tools cannot be used when running protractor tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, most likely, the problem with your application or a specific build of your application that you are testing against. Since the button becomes disabled on click, it looks like it is clicked and Protractor's job is done.

Some of the things you can try:

- [click *via JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34562061/771848) and see if it makes any difference:

  ```
  var link = $("#continueButtonID");
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", link.getWebElement());
  ```
- use the [console plugin](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) to explore the console errors - the application can be throwing an error when "continue" is clicked
- add a `browser.debugger();` call inside your test and manually explore the state of the app at this moment
- make sure, when you check the same logic manually, you are using the same exact build of the app as used for automated testing
- check if it is not a timing problem - one possibility is that it takes time for the next page to load and your follow-up tests assume they are on the desired page too early - you may need an extra explicit wait in this case

Follow-up read:

- [Debugging Protractor Tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#debugging-protractor-tests)